# how can we access data from google trends using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am accessing data from google trends using python with the help of pytrends api but after a sending limited request it raise an error : `RATE.LIMIT.ERROR.`

Rate Limit is not pubically known, trail & error suggest it is around 10/min. So how can i get data from google trends without getting  `RATE.LIMIT.ERROR.`

Any help plz.

Thank you.

Comment: Cache the result every 6-10 seconds in your server and use it from your server instead of directly pulling it from [Big Brother](http://google.com).

Comment: can you explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the last update of the README, we can have more details on the rate limit

> Rate Limit is not publicly known, let me know if you have a consistent estimate
>
> One user reports that 1,400 sequential requests of a 4 hours timeframe got them to the limit. (Replicated on 2 networks)
>
> It has been tested, and 60 seconds of sleep between requests (successful or not) is the correct amount once you reach the limit.